# Why non-capture group is not looping as defined?

Tags: regex, perl

Given the target string

`a{b}{c}{d}`

I am seeking for a regex that returns: `b`, `c`, `d` (the enclosed values between `{` and `}`.

I used the following regex: `[^{}]+(?:{([^{}]+)})+`
but it only returns the last value `d`.

I also tried to make the first match section `[^{}]+` lazy by changing it to `[^{}]+?` but no difference.

Why the non-capture group is not supporting the `+` quantifier?
Can you suggest a regex that will work?

**EDIT**

Keep looking and using the below answer from Wiktor Stribiżew I've found the following much more simple `([^{}]+)/g` which returns all strings without `{}` and i can easily skip the first item (the beginning of the string)

Comment: Your regex look fine to me. I type this: `[regex]::Match('a{b}{c}{d}','[^{}]+(?:{([^{}]+)})+').Groups[1].Captures` — in PowerShell and can see all three captures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the quantified capturing group because with each consecutive group value found, the previous one gets re-written (just what you observe). Use the `{([^{}]+)}` regex pattern (that captures the content between `{` and `}`) with the `/g` modifier to find multiple matches:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

$s = "a{b}{c}{d}";
my @res = ($s) =~ /{([^{}]+)}/g;
say "@res";
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/cXWrgn)

Regex breakdown:

- `{` - opening literal brace
- `([^{}]+)` - Group 1: one or more characters other than `{` and `}` (so, inside `{...}`, there can't be a `{`. If that is not what you need, replace with `([^}]+)`)
- `}` - closing literal brace

**NOTE**: If you use [`/([^{}]+)/g` regex](https://regex101.com/r/cN5qN9/1), it will match all substrings that consist of characters other than `{` and `}` and thus, will capture more than just texts inside `{...}`

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.